# Why doesn't my gridview's column click toggle the sort direction?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, gridview-sorting

Why doesn't my gridview's column click toggle the sort direction?

It seems to only sort the rows the first time I click on it, any other clicks just refreshes the page w/o any change in sort direction.

btw I have a OnSorting method that I call to update the sql query to sort.

My Code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvReport" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    AllowSorting="True"
    AllowPaging="True" 
    OnSorting="Report_OnSorting">



 public void Report_OnSorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {

}
```

Comment: Posting your GridView code from your .aspx page, and any code-behind might help identify the problem. There are a number of possible causes of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find your answer in the many replies to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213148/sort-columns-of-gridview-in-asp-net-c).

I believe that if you use the simplest version, ASP.Net will handle the whole sorting thing for you.

This code from a [SqlDataSource example](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/ctrlref/data/gridview.aspx) just sets AllowSorting="true" and provides SortExpressions in BoundColumns. It has no wiring up of the OnSorting event, and no other code. I believe it manages the toggling between ASC and DESC for you. In this case, using the dreaded SqlDataSource, I believe you have to use a DataSet and not a DataReader.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<html>
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
  <title>Sorting Data Using GridView</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
   <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AllowSorting="true" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
      AutoGenerateColumns="False">
      <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ID" DataField="au_id" SortExpression="au_id" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Last Name" DataField="au_lname" SortExpression="au_lname" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="First Name" DataField="au_fname" SortExpression="au_fname" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Phone" DataField="phone" SortExpression="phone" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Address" DataField="address" SortExpression="address" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="City" DataField="city" SortExpression="city" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="State" DataField="state" SortExpression="state" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Zip Code" DataField="zip" SortExpression="zip" />
        <asp:CheckBoxField HeaderText="Contract" SortExpression="contract" DataField="contract" />
      </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
   <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
      SelectCommand="SELECT [au_id], [au_lname], [au_fname], [phone], [address], [city], [state], [zip], [contract] FROM [authors]"
      ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Pubs %>" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I believe it can be done automatically if you set it up just right. For one thing, I don't think you need to set the OnSorting event or add code in it. But I think you might need to add BoundColumns with SortExpressions defined. Then, it's supposed to do the toggling between ASC and DESC for you.