# Gridview sorting and updatepanel

Tags: gridview, updatepanel

I am trying to use an update panel together with a gridview, but I am having some difficulties sorting the gridview. I tried to follow @dfowler in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213148/sort-columns-of-gridview-in-asp-net-c)

But when I try to sort I get this error when trying to databind the sorted list:
"The data source does not support server-side data paging."

Anyone having some clue what I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. When I first databinded to the gridview I used a List, but when I tried to rebind I used IQueryable instead, so a simple .ToList() worked :)

Answer (score 0):

I experienced 'The data source does not support server-side data paging' when I used IEnumerable(Of SomeClass) as my datasource, and as I used the 'yield return record;' to build this - there was no usual List(Of SomeClass) as the underlying object.  Linq queries may cause the same behaviour, try ToList() if this is the case.