# Search/Sort to display specific fields in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, search, gridview

Before I was binding my data to my GridView in the .cs file. I had searching/sorting working (search the database by typing in to a textbox, sort by selecting an option from a dropdownlist). However, now I'm binding my data in the .aspx file, and of course my sort/search isn't working anymore. How can I alter my sorting/searching algorithm so that the correct data binds???

(searchFill is the function that invokes searching/sorting)

.cs

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rootWebConfig = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/Cabot3");
        connectionString = rootWebConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["SecureODBConnectionString"];
        searchFill();
        GridViewRow row = DefaultGrid.SelectedRow;
        int rowIndex = DefaultGrid.SelectedIndex;
        HiddenGrid.SelectedIndex = rowIndex;
        GridViewRow row2 = HiddenGrid.SelectedRow;
        //int id = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[25].Text);
        fName = row2.Cells[0].Text;
        lName = row2.Cells[1].Text;
        addr = row2.Cells[2].Text;
        addr2 = row2.Cells[3].Text;
        city = row2.Cells[4].Text;
        state = row2.Cells[5].Text;
        zip = row2.Cells[6].Text;
        country = row2.Cells[7].Text;
        email = row2.Cells[8].Text;
        phone = row2.Cells[9].Text;
        ccType = row2.Cells[10].Text;
        ccNum = row2.Cells[11].Text;
        ccExp = row2.Cells[12].Text;
        length = row2.Cells[13].Text;
        delivery = row2.Cells[14].Text;
        price = row2.Cells[15].Text;
        source = row2.Cells[16].Text;
        joined = row2.Cells[17].Text;
        url = row2.Cells[18].Text;
        orderResults = row2.Cells[19].Text;
        pubName = row2.Cells[20].Text;
        sourceCode = row2.Cells[21].Text;
    }

    protected void searchFill()
    {
        orderByString = orderByList.SelectedItem.Value;
        fieldString = searchTextBox.Text;
        string sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM SecureOrders WHERE fName LIKE '%" + fieldString + "%' OR lName LIKE'%" + fieldString + "%' OR addr LIKE'%" + fieldString + "%' OR addr2 LIKE'%" + fieldString + "%' OR city LIKE'%" + fieldString + "%' OR state LIKE'%" + fieldString + "%' OR zip LIKE'%" + fieldString + "%' OR zip LIKE'%" + fieldString + "%' OR country LIKE'%" + fieldString + "%' OR email LIKE'%" + fieldString + "%' OR phone LIKE'%" + fieldString + "%' OR ccType LIKE'%" + fieldString + "%' OR ccNum LIKE'%" + fieldString + "%' OR ccExp LIKE'%" + fieldString + "%' OR cwaSource LIKE'%" + fieldString + "%' OR cwaJoined LIKE'%" + fieldString + "%' OR length LIKE'%" + fieldString + "%' OR delivery LIKE'%" + fieldString + "%' OR price LIKE'%" + fieldString + "%' OR url LIKE'%" + fieldString + "%' OR orderResults LIKE'%" + fieldString + "%' OR pubName LIKE'%" + fieldString + "%' OR sourceCode LIKE'%" + fieldString+ "%' ORDER BY " + orderByString;
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString.ToString()))
        using(SqlCommand searchSort = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, connection))
        {
            searchSort.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fieldString", fieldString);
            searchSort.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderByString", orderByString);

            connection.Open();
                searchSort.ExecuteNonQuery();             
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

.aspx

```
 <asp:GridView ID="DefaultGrid" 
        runat = "server"
        DataKeyNames = "IdentityColumn"
        onselectedindexchanged = "DefaultGrid_SelectedIndexChanged"
        autogenerateselectbutton = "True"
        enableviewstate = "False"
        selectedindex="0" DataSourceID="OrderSource" EnableModelValidation="True" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="Azure"
        forecolor="Black"
        font-bold="true" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Processed">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox
                ID="CheckBoxProcess"
                AutoPostBack = "true"
                Checked = '<%#Eval("processed") %>'
                OnCheckedChanged = "CheckBoxProcess_CheckedChanged"
                runat="server"
                Enabled = "true" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="fName" HeaderText="First Name" SortExpression="fName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="lName" HeaderText="Last Name" SortExpression="lName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="addr" HeaderText="Address" SortExpression="addr" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="email" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="email" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="phone" HeaderText="Phone" SortExpression="phone" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ccType" HeaderText="Credit Card Type" 
            SortExpression="ccType" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="length" HeaderText="Length" 
            SortExpression="length" />
    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="OrderSource" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SecureODBConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [SecureOrders]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this...

1. Write your stored procedure (as @coder says...the way you're doing it is not secure)

   CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.myPROC
       (@parm1 int = null, @parm2 int = null, ...)
       AS
       BEGIN

   ```
   SELECT
      field1,
      field2,
      field3,
      ...
   FROM
      Table
   WHERE
      (field1 = @parm1 or @parm1 is null)
      OR
      (field2 = @parm2 or @parm2 is null)

   END
   ```
2. Configure your datasource (use the wizard).

Once you identify your stored procedure to the datasource, it will ask you for the source values for each parameter identified in the stored procedure.  just fill-in the default value and leave the rest alone.  Basically what you want to end-up with is something like this (I'm not getting this syntactically correct -- but your intellisense will get it for you once you start):

```
...
<SELECT PARAMETERS>
   <PARAMETER name="parm1" type="integer">
   ...
</SELECT PARAMETERS>
```

1. Modify your searchFill() procedure to use the vars you created in your onload

me.datasource1.parameters.clear()
me.datassource.parameters("parm1").defaultvalue = fname;
me.datassource.parameters("parm2").defaultvalue = lname;
...

1. rebind your gridview

   me.gridview.databind

This isn't elegant, but it seems to fit with the approach you have taken so far.  Hope it helps.

Comment: Oh, by the way, the OrderBy clause wouldn't take a parameter for some reason - that's why it's written using variables :/

Comment: Yeah -- you can't orderby on a parameter.  You can write dynamic sql in your stored procedure (similar to how you constructed your sql-string oringally), but that a pain.  You can also sort your grid after you databind, and just not worry about orderby in your sql.

Comment: I didn't realize that GridView had a sort function - that made my life so much easier!

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass in parameters to the sql data source from code behind. Take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w1kdt8w2.aspx). 

Also, you want to be careful of sql injection attacks. You should never pass in a text box value directly to a sql statement. I hope you have a stored procedure in your actual code.

Comment: My OrderBy Clause would NOT take a parameter - that's why I'm using the text box value. Everything else in my code uses parameters...

Comment: You might want to implement sorting using  one of these techniques .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/213148/sort-columns-of-gridview-in-asp-net-c